# shell script with LFTP to get lasted file

Tags: shell, ftp, lftp

I trying to run a script that get a latest file create in my FTP server.

```
file=`ls -t -r | tail -n 1`

sudo lftp <<FTP
open $hostname
user $username $password
cd $folder
get $file
bye
FTP
```

But the ls command in file variable execute in my local machine. What´s wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Are you confusing `$file` with `$arquivo`?

Comment: yes, you're right, `ls` *is* being executed on your local machine. you'll need to run a preliminary ftp where the only commands you issue are `cd ... AND ls` AND then you need to capture that output (as you have done with file), AND then you need to parse that multi-line variable to find the newest file and store that as `file=`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Using `cls` instead of `ls` will help. Change `get $file` to

```
cls -1t|sed -n 1s/^/get\\ /p>/tmp/get
source /tmp/get
```

Beware, this uses the file `/tmp/get` and is not suited for concurrent operation.